# Assuming $U = A + iB$, where $A$, $B$ are hermitian and $U$ is unitary, show that $A^2 + B^2 = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be n x n hermitian matrices and $U$ an n x n unitary matrix.

Assuming that $U = A + iB$, I'm being asked to show the following:

(i) $A^2 + B^2 = I$

(ii) $[A,B] = AB - BA = 0$

My problem is that I can't seem to show (i) to be true without first assuming (ii). My working is as follows:

$$UU^\dagger = (A+iB)(A+iB)^\dagger = (A+iB)(A^\dagger - iB^\dagger) = (A+iB)(A-iB) = A^2 + B^2 + i(BA-AB) = I$$

So clearly (i) holds provided that the commutator $[A,B]=0$. But how do I show (i) without needing to assume that $A$ and $B$ commute? Alternatively, how can I show that they commute without having to assume (i)?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't realise that! Thank you.

Comment: @Paul There is no reason to assume that the "real and imaginary parts" are as nice as they seem; $A$ and $B$ may have non-real entries.

Comment: Are you certain that you were asked to show that you say you're asked to show? It looks like you may rather be supposed to show that (i) and (ii) are _equivalent_, not that they are both true.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I've double checked and this is what I'm being asked to show. It doesn't say anything about A and B being real valued matrices, either.

Comment: @Arthur Would leveraging the fact that $^\dagger = U^\dagger U$ work? This seems to give AB - BA = BA - AB, which implies that AB = BA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
(A+iB)(A^\star-iB^\star)
  &=AA^\star+iBA^\star-iAB^\star + BB^\star\\
  &=AA^\star +i(BA^\star-AB^\star) + BB^\star\\
  &=A^2+B^2+i(BA^\star-AB^\star)
\end{aligned}$$
Also
$$\begin{aligned}
(A^\star-iB^\star)(A+iB)
  &=AA^\star-iB^\star A+iA^\star B + BB^\star\\
  &=AA^\star-i(B^\star A-A^\star B) + BB^\star\\
  &=A^2+B^2-i(B A^\star-A B^\star)
\end{aligned}$$
Since $U = A+iB$ is unitary, we know that $U^\star$ is its inverse and so we know that $I=UU^\star=U^\star U$ and so
$$(A+iB)(A^\star-iB^\star)=(A^\star-iB^\star)(A+iB).$$
Therefore we can combine these pieces of information with the above derivations (subtract both) to conclude that
$
2i (BA^\star-AB^\star) = 0.
$
Then we find
$$
(A+iB)(A^\star-iB^\star) = A^2 + B^2.
$$
Combine with $I=UU^\star$ and you have the result.

Comment: Yup, absolutely. I realised after posting that I could have used the fact that $UU^\dagger = U^\dagger U$ to arrive at the same result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of @Rollen's answer is to use an anticommutator: $A^2+B^2=\frac12\{A+iB,\,A-iB\}$.